# Unsure of how to send an api auth key in vb

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to make a small stat checking app for Fortnite Battle Royale. The TRN Api requires a key to be sent, which I do not have a clue how to do. Thanks in advance.

```
Public Class Form1


Private Sub btnClose_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnClose.Click
    Me.Close()
End Sub

Private Sub btnSearch_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSearch.Click
    Dim webClient As New System.Net.WebClient
    Dim Platform As String = ""
    Dim UName As String = ""
    Dim TRNApiKey As String = "f4d79aad-381b-4b91-87f1-2a1c2ee14cb6"
    Dim fortniteStatslookup As String
    Dim URL As String

    Select Case cboPlatform.Text
        Case = "PC"
            Platform = "pc"
        Case = "Xbox"
            Platform = "xbl"
        Case = "Playstation"
            Platform = "psn"
    End Select

    UName = txtUName.Text

    URL = "https://api.fortnitetracker.com/v1/profile/" & Platform & "/" & UName

    webClient.Headers.Add("f4d79aad-381b-4b91-87f1-2a1c2ee14cb6", URL)
    fortniteStatslookup = webClient.DownloadString(URL)

    txtOutput.Text = fortniteStatslookup
End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: If I am not mistaken, the key should be the second parameter when you are adding the headers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See: [MSDN Webclient.Headers documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.headers(v=vs.110).aspx)

System.Net.WebClient.Headers take a key-value pair, so you will want something like:

```
webClient.Headers.Add("key", "f4d79aad-381b-4b91-87f1-2a1c2ee14cb6")
```

or

```
webClient.Headers.Add("APIkey", "f4d79aad-381b-4b91-87f1-2a1c2ee14cb6")
```